# Looping through files with perl

Tags: perl, file, loops

Okay I have 2 files. One file is data that is updated every 10 minutes while the second is data that was previously used. What I am trying to do is take one line from the new file and loop through each line of the second file and see if it matches one. If it does I dont want to use it, but if there is no match than I want to add it to a string. In what I have done so far it seems that the check does not ever find a match even though there is one. Here is what I have and a sample of the data I have been using from both files. CHECKHAIL and USEDHAIL are the two files

```
while(my $toBeChecked = <CHECKHAIL>){
        my $found = 0;
        seek USEDHAIL, 0, 0 or die "$0: seek: $!";
        while(my $hailCheck = <USEDHAIL>){
            if( $toBeChecked == $hailCheck){
                $found += 1;
            }
        }
        print USEDHAIL $toBeChecked;
        if ($found == 0){
            $toEmail .= $toBeChecked;
        }
    }
    print $toEmail;
    return;
}
```

CHECKHAIL sample data

```
2226  175   2 NE      LAWRENCE           DEADWOOD         SD    44.4    -103.7  (UNR)

2305  200   2 S       SISKIYOU           GREENVIEW        CA    41.52   -122.9  2 INCH HAIL REPORTED WITH STORM JUST SOUTH OF GREENVIEW. (MFR)

2350  200             DANIELS            E FLAXVILLE      MT    48.8    -105.17 GOLF BALL TO HEN EGG SIZED HAIL (GGW)

2350  175   5 N       DANIELS            RICHLAND         MT    48.89   -106.05 DESTROYED CROPS (GGW)
```

USEDHAIL sample data

```
2226  175   2 NE      LAWRENCE           DEADWOOD         SD    44.4    -103.7  (UNR)

2305  200   2 S       SISKIYOU           GREENVIEW        CA    41.52   -122.9  2 INCH HAIL REPORTED WITH STORM JUST SOUTH OF GREENVIEW. (MFR)
```

Comment: This sounds like a mighty bad idea and the complexity of the task is going to by O(n**2). Just put the data in a database, add a primary key constraint on whatever defines it as UNIQUE, add another column `date_entered DEFAULTS CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`, and then SELECT where the `date_entered > TODAY - '1 day'::interval`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why wouldn't you just create a hash for the first (used) file?

```
use strict; 
use warnings;
my %fromUsedFile;
open USEDFILE, '<', '/the/data/file/that/is/10minutesold';
$fromUsedFile{$_}++  while <USEDFILE>;
close USEDFILE;

while ($toBeChecked = <CHECKHAIL>) {
    if (defined $fromUsedFile{$toBeChecked}) {
        # ... line is in both the new and old file
    } else {
        # ... line is only in the new file
        $toBeEmailed .= $toBeChecked;
    }
}
```

Comment: Because I dont know how to create a hash. I will try this though

Comment: this is giving me syntax errors for $usedFileName and $fromUSedFile. What declaration am I supposed to make with those

Comment: @shinjuo - answer updated to work more out of the box with `strict` enabled.

Comment: This worked very well. I appreciate the help. I am still reading the learning perl O'Reilly Books so I will hopefully get to hashs soon

Answer (score 3):

It never has an opportunity to succeed because of

```
while(<USEDHAIL>){
    my $hailCheck = $_;
    if( $toBeChecked eq $hailCheck){
        $found += 1;
    }else{
        return;  ### XXX
    }
}
```

On the first mismatch, the sub returns to its caller. You may have meant `next` instead, but for conciseness, you should remove the whole `else` clause. Remove the other `else { return; }` (corresponding to when `$found` is true) for the same reason.

Note that your algorithm has quadratic complexity and will be slow for large inputs. It'd be better to read the used records into a hash and then for each line of `CHECKHAIL` probe the `%used` hash to see whether it's been processed.

With those lines removed, I get

```
$ ./prog.pl 

2305  200   2 S       SISKIYOU           GREENVIEW        CA    41.52   -122.9  2 INCH HAIL REPORTED WITH STORM JUST SOUTH OF GREENVIEW. (MFR)

2350  200             DANIELS            E FLAXVILLE      MT    48.8    -105.17 GOLF BALL TO HEN EGG SIZED HAIL (GGW)

2350  175   5 N       DANIELS            RICHLAND         MT    48.89   -106.05 DESTROYED CROPS (GGW)
```

As you can see, that still has a bug. You need to rewind `USEDHAIL` for each line of `CHECKHAIL`:

```
seek USEDHAIL, 0, 0 or die "$0: seek: $!";
while(<USEDHAIL>){
...
```

This produces

```
$ ./prog.pl 
2350  200             DANIELS            E FLAXVILLE      MT    48.8    -105.17 GOLF BALL TO HEN EGG SIZED HAIL (GGW)
2350  175   5 N       DANIELS            RICHLAND         MT    48.89   -106.05 DESTROYED CROPS (GGW)
```

For an example of a better way to do it, consider

```
#! /usr/bin/perl

use warnings;
use strict;

sub read_used_hail {
  my($path) = @_;

  my %used;

  open my $fh, "<", $path or die "$0: open $path: $!";

  local $" = " ";  # " fix Stack Overflow highlighting
  while (<$fh>) {
    chomp;
    my @f = split " ", $_, 10;
    next unless @f;
    ++$used{"@f"};
  }

  wantarray ? %used : \%used;
}

my %used = read_used_hail "used-hail";
open my $check, "<", "check-hail" or die "$0: open: $!";

while (<$check>) {
  chomp;
  my @f = split " ", $_, 10;
  next if !@f || $used{join " " => @f};
  print $_, "\n";
}
```

Sample run:

```
$ ./prog.pl 
2350  200             DANIELS            E FLAXVILLE      MT    48.8    -105.17 GOLF BALL TO HEN EGG SIZED HAIL (GGW)
2350  175   5 N       DANIELS            RICHLAND         MT    48.89   -106.05 DESTROYED CROPS (GGW)
```

Comment: Where would I put my file paths at in this. I am pretty new to perl if you cant tell and some of this is stuff I have never used.

Comment: The code above hardcodes the unimaginative names `check-hail` and `used-hail` for your two input files.

Comment: The edited code I used above is what I tried and it did not work still. I am now going to try to work with what you just gave me and see where that goes.

Comment: On a side note what is wrong with the code i posted above. It looks like the code you used and yet it still doesnt work?

Comment: Your updated code should have `if( $toBeChecked eq $hailCheck){` rather than `==` because you're comparing strings. To be able to append records to the end of the used file, make sure to open it in read-and-append mode, e.g., `open USEDHAIL, ">>+", $path`, and don't forget to `seek` to the beginning before all reads.

Answer (score 1):

Using $_ within an inner loop can cause problems. Try naming your lines first like so:

```
while(my $toBeChecked = <CHECKHAIL>){
    my $found = 0;
    while( my $hailCheck = <USEDHAIL>){
```

Also perl sees numeric comparison and string comparison differently. You're using string comparison instead of numeric comparison:

```
 if ($found eq 0){
```

Change to:

```
 if ($found == 0){
```

Comment: That is very helpful to know but I am still getting the same problem

Comment: Also, are you certain the lines are exactly the same? White space differences would also cause it to not match

Comment: It should I just copied and pasted from one file to the other

Comment: if its a special white space, tab for one, that doesn't always copy correctly.  copy from one file into two new files and use those for check and use.

Answer (score 1):

This line sticks out for me:

```
if ($found eq 0){
```

Since `$found` is a boolean, perform boolean tests on it:

```
if (not $found) {
```

It also looks like your logic is a bit reversed -- in the first `if`, you return if the lines *do not match*, and then in the second `if`, you return if there was a match.  **Do you perhaps intend to say `next;` to skip out of the innermost loop, instead?**

Comment: Still not working. Did you mean to do if($found){
and then put the concatination in the }else{ part? Thats what I tried

Comment: I dont even need the first else actually, I just want to test if it is a match.